# Executing a function only after another given function has been completely executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this piece of code, and because of synchronization issues I need to make sure all of this MathJax stuff has been executed before I can run the `setConsoleWidth()` function. How can I do so?
I'd prefer a native solution, but I don't really mind using jQuery.

```
window.updateConsole = function() {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender",MathJax.Hub,"math"]);
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
    var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("mathDiv")[0];

    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text", math, "R( \\theta ) = sin^{ \\class{hover P}{" + P.show + "} } \\left ( \\frac{\\class{hover B}{" + sign_mult(B.show) + "} ⋅ \\class{hover S}{" + sign_mult(S.show) + "} ⋅ \\class{hover J}{" + sign_mult(J.show) + "} ⋅ \\theta ⋅ ( \\theta \\class{hover S}{" + sign_sum(-(S.show)) + "})}{\\class{hover N}{" + N.show + "}} \\right ) \\;  \\mapsto  \\;  \\left\\{\\begin{array}i x(\\theta) = \\class{hover C}{" + C.show + "} \\class{hover E}{"  + sign_sum(E.show) + "} ⋅ R(\\theta) ⋅ cos^{\\class{hover H}{" + H.show + "}}(\\theta)\\\\y(\\theta) =\\class{hover D}{" + D.show + "} \\class{hover F}{" + sign_sum(F.show) + "} ⋅ R(\\theta) ⋅ sin^{\\class{hover Z}{" + Z.show + "}}(\\theta)\\end{array}\\right."]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(setConsoleWidth);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(console.log(Console.scrollWidth));
  });
};

function setConsoleWidth() {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
    var w = Console.scrollWidth, W = window.innerWidth*0.85;

    if (w > W) {
      console.log("bingo");
      math.style.fontSize = (2.8*W/w)+"vw";
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Is `Rerender` synchronous or not? You need to have some way to tell when the Rerender is done. Same for the `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text"` line

Comment: Could you just put setConsoleWidth(); right under your MathJax.Hub.Queue call, inside the body of that anonymous callback function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not quite sure, but I believe most of MathJax is asynchronous. Maybe  someone more experienced with MathJax can help us out.

Comment: @Kulix I don't think so, but I could be wrong. I'm trying to rescale an expression to fit a given width by calculating how off it is and then setting it's font size properly. This means the expression must be fully loaded with the wrong size so that it can be messured and scaled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your console function to the queue at the very end, to ensure it executes only once all the previous actions are completed:

```
window.updateConsole = function() {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender",MathJax.Hub,"math"]);
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
    var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("mathDiv")[0];

    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text", math, "R( \\theta ) = sin^{ \\class{hover P}{" + P.show + "} } \\left ( \\frac{\\class{hover B}{" + sign_mult(B.show) + "} ⋅ \\class{hover S}{" + sign_mult(S.show) + "} ⋅ \\class{hover J}{" + sign_mult(J.show) + "} ⋅ \\theta ⋅ ( \\theta \\class{hover S}{" + sign_sum(-(S.show)) + "})}{\\class{hover N}{" + N.show + "}} \\right ) \\;  \\mapsto  \\;  \\left\\{\\begin{array}i x(\\theta) = \\class{hover C}{" + C.show + "} \\class{hover E}{"  + sign_sum(E.show) + "} ⋅ R(\\theta) ⋅ cos^{\\class{hover H}{" + H.show + "}}(\\theta)\\\\y(\\theta) =\\class{hover D}{" + D.show + "} \\class{hover F}{" + sign_sum(F.show) + "} ⋅ R(\\theta) ⋅ sin^{\\class{hover Z}{" + Z.show + "}}(\\theta)\\end{array}\\right."]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(setConsoleWidth);
  });
};
```

Comment: It still doesn't fix it... When I consolelog `Console.scrollWidth` after running the `setConsoleWidth()` function it always returns the previus `scrollWidth`, not the current one. I need a way to only execute `setConsoleWidth()` after completely loading the MathJax expression first... (Take a look at the code snip, I updated it so you guys could understand what `setConsoleWidth()` does).

Comment: It could be that `MathJax` completely clears its queue before the page layout gets changed - maybe something async under the hood is causing it. What happens when you wrap `setConsoleWidth` in a timeout? `MathJax.Hub.Queue(() => setTimeout(setConsoleWidth, 50));`

Comment: It works! I did `setTimeout(setConsoleWidth, 5000));` and checked `Console.scrollWidth` before the page ran `setConsoleWidth()` and consoleloged the `scrollWidth` itself. The values seem to always match. We might run into a problem if the MathJax expression get's too long: the longer it gets the longer the page will take to render it and it might surpass our 50 milliseconds `Timout`, which means the program will return an incorrect value for `Console.scrollWidth`. It works anyway... Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I found out your original solution was working just fine. There was an unrelated issue which was messing things up, but the timing worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe this (assuming that the calls within `MathJax.Hub.Queue(function (){}` are synchronous) :

```
window.updateConsole = function () {
    function done() {
        setConsoleWidth();
    }
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender", MathJax.Hub, "math"]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
        var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("mathDiv")[0];
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text", math, "R( \\theta ) = sin^{ \\class{hover P}{" + P.show + "} } \\left ( \\frac{\\class{hover B}{" + sign_mult(B.show) + "} ⋅ \\class{hover S}{" + sign_mult(S.show) + "} ⋅ \\class{hover J}{" + sign_mult(J.show) + "} ⋅ \\theta ⋅ ( \\theta \\class{hover S}{" + sign_sum(-(S.show)) + "})}{\\class{hover N}{" + N.show + "}} \\right ) \\;  \\mapsto  \\;  \\left\\{\\begin{array}i x(\\theta) = \\class{hover C}{" + C.show + "} \\class{hover E}{" + sign_sum(E.show) + "} ⋅ R(\\theta) ⋅ cos^{\\class{hover H}{" + H.show + "}}(\\theta)\\\\y(\\theta) =\\class{hover D}{" + D.show + "} \\class{hover F}{" + sign_sum(F.show) + "} ⋅ R(\\theta) ⋅ sin^{\\class{hover Z}{" + Z.show + "}}(\\theta)\\end{array}\\right."]);

        done();
    });
};
```

Comment: Why did you create a `done` function? And are you sure that the first and last `Queue` calls aren't also async?

Comment: Well, I thought about that. I basically made assumptions they were sync calls.

Comment: Those are not sync functions... Here's the [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/synchronize.html).